# origin (or cursor) to selected vertice?

Tags: modeling

How can i get the cursor to the selected vertice?
And, since this always error on me, how do i set the origin to the mirror plane on mirrored geometry? I get lots of geometry where the origin is wayyyy off.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Shift S > Cursor to Selected, but if you have the On Cage option enabled in the Subdivision Surface modifier, it won't work as the vertex is not really at the position it seems to be

Comment: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2387/can-a-punishment-be-implemented-for-using-the-word-vertice-in-a-q-a

Answer (score 1):

Found it!!

shift + s and then i could find the option to do what i needed in the popup menu!